# cmake & qt проблемы

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Возникла проблема: не могу собрать проект использующий `qt` с помощью `cmake` (сам код верный, так как его можно собрать с помощью `pro`-file. Мой `cmake`-файл:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(calculator)

add_definitions(-Wall -std=c++14)

include_directories(include)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
include_directories(Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

set(MAIN_SRC sources/main.cpp)
file(GLOB CALC_SRC "sources/calc/*.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${MAIN_SRC} ${CALC_SRC})

qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Widgets)
```

Код:

```
//calculator.hpp

#pragma once

#include <QWidget>
#include <QStack>

class QLCDNumber;
class QPushButton;

class Calculator : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QLCDNumber *    m_plcd;
    QStack<QString> m_stk;
    QString         m_strDisplay;

public:
    Calculator (QWidget * pwgt = 0);
    QPushButton * createButton(const QString & str);
    void         calculate();

public slots:
    void slotButtonClicked();
};


//main.cpp

#include <QApplication>
#include "calculator.hpp"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Calculator   calculator;

    calculator.setWindowTitle("Calculator");
    calculator.resize(230, 200);

    calculator.show(); 

    return app.exec();
}

//calculator.cpp
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "calculator.hpp"

Calculator::Calculator(QWidget* pwgt/*= 0*/) : QWidget(pwgt)
{
    m_plcd = new QLCDNumber(12);
    m_plcd->setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber::Flat);
    m_plcd->setMinimumSize(150, 50);

    QChar aButtons[4][4] = {{'7', '8', '9', '/'},
                            {'4', '5', '6', '*'},
                            {'1', '2', '3', '-'},
                            {'0', '.', '=', '+'}
                           };

    //Layout setup
    QGridLayout* ptopLayout = new QGridLayout;
    ptopLayout->addWidget(m_plcd, 0, 0, 1, 4);    
    ptopLayout->addWidget(createButton("CE"), 1, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
           ptopLayout->addWidget(createButton(aButtons[i][j]), i + 2, j);
        }
    }
    setLayout(ptopLayout);
}

QPushButton* Calculator::createButton(const QString& str)
{
    QPushButton* pcmd = new QPushButton(str);
    pcmd->setMinimumSize(40, 40);
    connect(pcmd, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(slotButtonClicked()));
    return pcmd;
}


void Calculator::calculate()
{
    qreal   fOperand2    = m_stk.pop().toFloat();
    QString strOperation = m_stk.pop();
    qreal   fOperand1    = m_stk.pop().toFloat();
    qreal   fResult      = 0;

    if (strOperation == "+") {
        fResult = fOperand1 + fOperand2;
    }
    if (strOperation == "-") {
        fResult = fOperand1 - fOperand2;
    }
    if (strOperation == "/") {
        fResult = fOperand1 / fOperand2;
    }
    if (strOperation == "*") {
        fResult = fOperand1 * fOperand2;
    }
    m_plcd->display(fResult);
}

void Calculator::slotButtonClicked()
{
    QString str = ((QPushButton*)sender())->text();

    if (str == "CE") {
        m_stk.clear();
        m_strDisplay = "";
        m_plcd->display("0");
        return;
    }
    if (str.contains(QRegExp("[0-9]"))) {
        m_strDisplay += str;
        m_plcd->display(m_strDisplay.toDouble());
    }
    else if (str == ".") {
        m_strDisplay += str;
        m_plcd->display(m_strDisplay);
    }
    else {
        if (m_stk.count() >= 2) {
            m_stk.push(QString().setNum(m_plcd->value()));
            calculate();
            m_stk.clear();
            m_stk.push(QString().setNum(m_plcd->value()));
            if (str != "=") {
                m_stk.push(str);
            }
        }
        else {
            m_stk.push(QString().setNum(m_plcd->value()));
            m_stk.push(str);
            m_strDisplay = "";
        }
    }
}
```

На стадии линковки выдает ошибку:

```
CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/sources/main.cpp.o: In function `Calculator::~Calculator()':
/home/andrej/Public/example/qt_calculator/sources/main.cpp:(.text._ZN10CalculatorD2Ev[_ZN10CalculatorD2Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to `vtable for Calculator'
CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/sources/calc/Calculator.cpp.o: In function `Calculator::Calculator(QWidget*)':
/home/andrej/Public/example/qt_calculator/sources/calc/Calculator.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `vtable for Calculator'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/build.make:123: recipe for target 'calculator' failed
make[2]: *** [calculator] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: а Ваш cmake запускает moc?

Comment: @KoVadim вроде должен: стоят строки `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)`
`set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)`

Comment: `file(GLOB MOC_HDRS
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*/*.h
)`
`add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
    SHARED
    ${M_SRCS}
    ${SRCS}
    ${RSCS}
    ${HDRS}
    ${MOC_HDRS}
)`

Заголовков не хватает наверное. Посмотрел как у нас проекты прописаны, для библиотеки пример

Comment: А нет, вру. Где ваш деструктор ? `virtual ~Calculator(){}`

Comment: @vegorov я его не делал. по умолчанию стоит

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch добавьте на всякий случай

Comment: @vegorov без него все и так компилируется (через pro-файл)

Comment: А вы же в при сборки запускаете moc генератор и компилируете созданные moc_ файлы?

Comment: @Unick это должен сделать сам cmake (там ведь прописано CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

Comment: А вы же можете привести весь лог сборки?

Comment: @Unick [ 20%] Automatic moc, uic and rcc for target calculator
[ 20%] Built target calculator_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target calculator
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/sources/main.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/sources/calc/Calculator.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/calculator.dir/calculator_automoc.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable calculator  а остальное есть в вопросе

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [cmake, qt и проект разнесенный по каталогам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853509/cmake-qt-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bc)

Comment: @Arhad не думаю, что он является дубликатом хотя бы на том основании, что он был задан раньше "оригинала".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь использованы `AUTOUIC` и `AUTOMOC` свойства, которые включают функционал CMake для генерации `ui` и `moc`. Но, чтобы они правильно работали, необходимо в списке файлов исходного кода также иметь файлы заголовков. Это нужно для того, чтобы CMake смог заглянуть в сами файлы и понять нужно ли генерировать для них `ui` и `moc` шаги компиляции.

Подробнее - [в документации](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#manual:cmake-qt(7)).

---

Функция `qt5_use_modules` депрецирована и использовать её не имеет особого смысла в современных версиях Qt. Достаточно `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets)`. И вызов функции `include_directories(Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)` можно удалить потому, что `target_link_libraries` добавит транзитивные зависимости, которые включают пути к файлам заголовков и линковку библиотек.

Answer (score 0):

Проблемы явно не в CMake а где-то ещё:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал папку, положил туда main.cpp и calculator.cpp/hpp, CMakeLists.txt с Вашего вопроса, открыла в qtcreator, поправил CMakeLists.txt :

```
set(MAIN_SRC sources/main.cpp)
file(GLOB CALC_SRC "sources/calc/*.cpp")
```

поменял на

```
set(MAIN_SRC main.cpp)
file(GLOB CALC_SRC "calc*.cpp")
```

собрал, запустил - результат записал и прикрепил.

Comment: А у вас точно данный CmakeLists.txt используется?

Comment: На картинке же видно. Там две исправленные строки подсвечены. Надо было текстом добавить, но я уже не на работе. Картинку если открыть и приблизить там всё видно

Comment: Проблема не может быть не в cmake, так как про-файл все собирает.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch внёс правки в сообщение. XUbuntu 16, qtcreator 4.5+, qt 5.10 (и qtcreator и qt собраны вручную из исходников, брал последние версии доступные в тот день), cmake версию сейчас не могу посмотреть, но явно выше 3.5, стандартная из репы XUbuntu 16 ([3.5.1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/cmake) видимо).

Comment: Странно: если заношу все в один каталог, то все собирается, но стоит разнести по каталогам - и ничего. Вроде нашел из-за чего: генерируемый файл `calculator_automoc.cpp` содержит не верную информацию, а moc_calculator.cpp вообще не генерируется!

Comment: заголовочный файл должен лежать рядом с файло исходников, иначе moc не поймёт это класс, который нужно обработать. Перенесите `calculator.hpp` в каталог `src`, и всё будет хорошо

Comment: да я это уже понял) Но, по мне, это как-то совсем кривенько. Тобишь я обычно размещаю проект в трех папках: include, sources и build (последняя для сборки) - и тут, оказывается, что qt проект нужно запихивать в одну папку... Не очень комильфо... Есть ли другое решение?

Comment: Не всё приложение, а только QObject наследников.

Comment: это понятно, что не все, но вот только заголовочные файлы с наследниками включаются и в другие части кода. Значит нужно либо держать два заголовочных файла (один из которых в папке include) либо включать папку sources как инклюд директорию (а в ней еще могут содержаться внутри папки) - корочь жесть