# cmake, qt и проект разнесенный по каталогам

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Вопрос вытек из моего предыдущего вопроса: [cmake & qt проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853222/cmake-qt-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Оказалось, что если все файлы закинуть в одну папку, то все успешно компилируется, но стоит их разнести по разным каталогам, как все перестает работать... Тобишь: если заголовочный файл для класса с `Q_OBJECT` разместить в том же каталоге, что и `.cpp` файл с реализацией этого класса - то все работает. Но если заголовочный файл вынести в папку `include`, то все накрывается медным тазом.

Почему? Можно ли все-таки собирать подобные проекты для `qt` и как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш заголовочный файл не был указан в списке, передаваемом в `add_executable()`.

По умолчанию CMake пытается для каждого известного `*.cpp` найти в той же папке его `*.h`‐ или `*.hpp`‐пару. Благодаря этому ваш изначальный случай и собирался как задумано — CMake угадывал имя и расположение заголовочного файла и передавал его `moc`-у вместе со всеми прочими заголовочными файлами.

Про вашу же папку `include` CMake ничего не знает. Поэтому **необходимо сделать одно из двух**:

- явно поместить заголовочный файл (или файлы по glob-маске) в проект (то есть куда-нибудь внутрь `add_executable()`), давая возможность обработать этот файл всем, кто подписался на обработку `*.hpp`, в том числе и `moc`;
- либо воспользоваться тем, что `moc`, встретив при сканировании `*.cpp`-файла конструкцию вида `#include "moc_имя.cpp"`, начинает искать для обработки файл `имя.h`/`имя.hpp` во всех местах, указанных как папки с заголовочными файлами (в том числе и по списку `include_directories()`). Иными словами, надо заменить строку:

  ```
  #include "calculator.hpp"
  ```

  на:

  ```
  #include "moc_calculator.cpp"
  ```

Comment: Первый способ работает! Спасибо) Но не совсем разобрался со вторым (который выглядит предпочтительнее), наверно я что-то не так делаю: как правильно указать опцию `moc` если у меня заголовочный файл лежит в папку `include` в той же папке, что и `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC_MOC_OPTIONS -Iinclude)` где-нибудь после `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)`? Сейчас проверю у себя.

Comment: конкретно так не работает - по крайней мере на версии 3.5 cmake

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, исправил второй пункт на гарантированно работающий способ. Проверял на связке CMake 3.9.1 и Qt 5.6.1.